# Структура БД площадки

Tags: mysql, sql

Возник вопрос в разработке системы продажи товаров. Существуют два типа пользователей:

1. только продают товары
2. только покупают

Половина полей у них совпадает, разные поля буду хранить в дополнительных таблицах. Появился вопрос в проектировании таблицы заказов. Нужно будет хранить всю историю заказов. Со временем товар может удалятся из БД, но в истории нужно его показывать, я думаю нужно сделать еще дополнительную таблицу, где будет хранится название товара.

*sellers* - таблица хранения дополнительных полей для тех кто продает товары.
*clients* - для покупателей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не удаляйте товар. Сделайте ему поле "удален", и в продажах показывайте только не удаленные. А в истории просто все. А то потом кроме названия захотят увидеть какие цены на него были и т.п.

Comment: ок. А как быть с тем, что товар можна купить в порциях или в кг. В таблице products у меня есть два поля для цены, а вот как это лучше хранить в заказах.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает что многие поля из orders должны переехать в order_details, ведь по одному заказу наверное можно купить один товар в кг, а второй в в порциях. И количество же не на весь заказ, а на каждый компонент. И фиксировать цену по которой покупка прямо в details ибо на нее может быть наложена какая нибудь скидка, например. Или со временем в products цены поменяются, а в старых заказах они должны сохранится. И со временем цены могут стать вообще отдельной подсистемой, захотят градации от количества, еще от каких признаков ...

Comment: вот еще вопрос один возникает, сейчас получается 1 заказ - 1товар. Интересует что бы было в таком виде: Заказ №2456 (1 товар ...... n-товар)

Comment: если вы поля относящиеся к позиции перенесете в details то у вас будет n товаров на заказ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Считаю, что на ваш вопрос нельзя дать единственно правильный ответ. Тут есть место и для субъективных оценок и для специфических требований.

Что точно не так:

- Отношение users к sellers и clients не может быть 1:M, только 1:1.
- Часть полей в вашем orders относится к Товарной позиции, а не к Заказу в целом.

В порядке рекомендации:

- Объединить users+sellers+clients в одну таблицу. Пусть неиспользуемые в кокретном случае поля хранят значения по умолчанию или null. Заведите роли пользователя или доп. атрибуты "продавец" и "покупатель". Во первых вы упростите запросы. Во вторых станет возможным выступать в разных ролях, почему бы и нет!
- Ничего не удалять, вместо этого отмечать записи как неактивные.
- Вынести цены из products в отдельную таблицу prices 1:M, чтобы сделать возможным оптовые скидки, разные упаковки и т.п.

Comment: уточняю по поводу цен, при добавлении товара в продажу нужно указывать две цены. Первая за кг, вторая за порцию. В итоге тогда моя таблица должна выглядить вот так: prices (id,price_one, price_two, product_id) ?

Comment: Я предполагал, что будет две записи: по одной на каждую цену. В перспективе много разных цен на товар. Структура может быть такая: (product_id int, kind enum, price decimal, primary key(product_id, kind))